# Standard Model searching for new physics in the wrong direction?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model, elementary-particles

What makes the SM so confident that any possible new discrete elementary particles must exist outside and separated from the known elementary particles?

**What is the definitive theoretical proof we have that elementary particles do not posses any inner structure?**

Maybe the supersymmetric partner we are looking for is hidden inside the known particle?

Maybe finding an inner structure will resolve almost all today's physics unknowns and prove that there were always emergent phenomena of the possible intrinsic mechanics of particles.

Why this obsession looking to the outside and not looking for any inner structure of the known particles of the SM? Would that not be the next logical step and was not this the direction particle physics was looking in the past? Why we suddenly changed direction from the inside to the outside although there is no definite evidence or prove that elementary particles have no inner structure thus there could be not elementary after all?

Abandon this direction of research and possibility may prove not fruitful?

Should we continue this path of research based solely on what has become more or less a dogma thus, that elementary particles have no inner structure.

Comment: There have been many experiments probing (possible) internal structure of various particles.

Answer (score 5):

**What makes the SM so confident that any possible new discrete elementary particles must exist outside and separated from the known elementary particles?**

Nothing, we really are searching for breaking points of the SM

**What is the definitive theoretical proof we have that elementary particles do not posses any inner structure?**

Perhaps you would like to read string theory, there fundamental particles' properties are determined by the internal state of some "strings", things like charge are different modes of vibration.

**Maybe the supersymmetric partner we are looking for is hidden inside the known particle?**

No idea what this even means, so I'll pass on this one.

**Why this obsession looking to the outside and not looking for any inner structure of the known particles of the SM? Would that not be the next logical step and was not this the direction particle physics was looking in the past? Why we suddenly changed direction from the inside to the outside although there is no definite evidence or prove that elementary particles have no inner structure thus there could be not elementary after all?**

Arguably we have never stopped zooming into fundamental particles, remember that energy ~ inverse distance so when you hear a physicist say: "We need an accelerator with larger energies" what they should really been saying is "We need a more powerful microscope".

Comment: "We need an accelerator with larger energies" what they should really been saying is "We need a more powerful microscope". These are not just microscopes but also energy amplifiers. I'm worried that this is not the correct way to go. The added energy disrupts any energy manifold elementary particles may have at their rest energy. In other words the particle deforms. One should try  less intrusive method of "looking inside" close as possible to their rest state.